# Joining table with range ID matching

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I currently have 2 tables which needs to be joined.

The first table is a big table,millions of records. The second is a matching table.
I would want to join the 2 table. A table of the intended result is shown below.
I would need tips on how to write the SQL to join the 2 tables.

```
    Table 1

    ID X   Column X
    1      X1
    2      X2
    3      X3
    4      X4
    5      X5
    6      X6
    ...  ...
    the list goes on

    Table 2

    ID   Column Y
    1    Y1
    3    Y2
    6    Y3
    11   Y4


    Intended result

    ID X   Column X  Column Y
    1      X1        Y1
    2      X2        Y1
    3      X3        Y2
    4      X4        Y2
    5      X5        Y2
    6      X6        Y3
    7      X7        Y3
    8      X8        Y3
    9      X9        Y3
    10     X10       Y3
    11     X11       Y4
    12     X12       Y4
```

Comment: I dont understand how you could join these tables and expect a result like ` 2      X2        Y1` because no record exists in [table 2]  to join [id] 2, so the result would be ` 2      X2        NULL`, on a left outer join.  and the result wouldnt exist on an inner join.

Comment: He wants to match everything whose ID is in the range between two rows in table 2. See my answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT idX, columnX, columnY
FROM (
    SELECT id, columnY, @prevID AS prevID, @prevID := id
    FROM table2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevID := NULL) init
    ORDER BY id DESC) AS t2
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.idX >= t2.id AND (t2.prevID IS NULL OR t1.idX < t2.prevID)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdbd1/1)

Comment: This is actually working in mySQL? How is the performance for a larger number of rows as this must process serially like a cursor?

Comment: It processes table 2 serially, but the join with table 1 can use an index on idX.

Comment: Hi Barmar, but when i run this on MS-SQL. 
It returns me Incorrect syntax near ':'. for the @prevID := id

Comment: This answer is for MySQL, I don't know MS-SQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT T1.IDX, T1.ColumnX , T2.ColumnY FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.IDX = T2.ID
```

Comment: This won't work for the IDs in table 1 that aren't in table 2.

Answer (score -1):

I guess to get the intended result you need to use inner join as:

```
select t1.id, t1.X, t2.Y from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Userful Links:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

[Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Edited:

Oh I didn't check that rows don't match. I tried this way. It worked for me:

```
select t1.id, t1.x,
if(t2.y != 'null',t2.y,(select y from table2 t3 where t3.id < t1.id order by t3.id desc limit 1)) as 'y'
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: This isn't matching on the range between IDs in table 2.